# ambiguous relative clause '' who ''?

Tags: grammaticality

What does '' who '' refer to ? Is this sentence grammatically correct ?

There was a friend of this woman, who loves me.

Comment: Hi. Where did you find this sentence? What is the context?

Comment: Your example sentence is ambiguous and poorly punctuated. Where did you encounter it?

Comment: I wanted to say that the one who loves me is this woman's friend. Did I write it wrong?

Comment: “This woman has a friend who loves me”? But if that’s what you mean, then why the past tense *there **was***?

Comment: Or “One of this woman’s friends loves me”?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum  A love triangle that became a love duo would explain the tenses (was ... loves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a poorly constructed sentence. You could probably create a context in which it would be valid, but it would be unusual.

I think your question is about the "who" part. So if you change the tense to agree, it helps:

> (1) There is a friend of this woman who loves me.
>
> (2) There is a friend of this woman, who loves me.

I believe that:

In (1), **who** refers to the woman.

In (2), **who** refers to the friend.